# Is it necessary to escape a backslash in a config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, .net-core

Say I have the following string:

```
c:\testmypath
```

In C#, if I want to use that inside code without a tab appearing inside it, I can do the following:

```
string t = @"c:\testmypath";
```

However, if I want to read this from a configuration file; let's say an `appsettings.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "MyPath": "c:\testmypath"
}
```

The following code results in a tab being displayed in the console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = returnString();

    Console.WriteLine(path);
    Console.ReadLine();
}


static string returnString()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    var configuration = builder.Build();

    return configuration["MyPath"];            
}
```

I can fix this by escaping the path inside the config file; for example:

```
{
  "MyPath": "c:\\testmypath"
}
```

By, can I escape the single slash version somehow?  I've tried:

```
return @configuration["MyPath"];
```

Which, to my surprise, does compile, but has no effect.  I've also tried `.ToString()`, although I'm not sure why I thought that would work.

Comment: `@configuration` is different than `@"configuration"` - the second doesn't parse escape characters in the string, the first doesn't consider the identifier as a keyword (so you can have a variable like e.g. `@this`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C# and JSON are different languages with different syntactic rules (after all, JSON doesn't look much like C#), albeit their rules regarding how strings look are kind of similar.

Since you're dealing with a JSON file, C#'s rules for strings (verbatim strings in particular) don't apply, but JSON's rules do. In those rules you *have* to escape a backslash as `\\` every time. There is no other way. Otherwise the sequence `\t` actually means Tab, as you noticed.

There is no real way of fixing this after the fact. Depending on the character after `\` you'd get something, like the Tab, or get a parsing error when trying to read the JSON file. While you could turn Tab back into `\t` if you know you're dealing with file paths I wouldn't recommend it. As mentioned, if the character after the backslash isn't a `t`, you might get an error anyway without a chance to recover.

As for your attempt of “escaping” the wrong version on the C# side: `@` has different meaning, depending on where it's used:

- `@"string"` is a *verbatim string* in which almost anything can be written *verbatim* without having to worry about escape characters. The only exception is `""` for double quotes inside the string. But indeed, it's most commonly-used and handy for things like file paths on Windows and regular expressions, both of which are rather annoying to type when having to escape every single backslash.
- `@name` makes any keyword or other name a valid identifier. You can prefix every identifier with `@` and this would make a valid program slightly longer, but doesn't change anything about its semantics. It's purely something for the compiler, similar to, e.g. `using` directives.

While both features use the same character and have somewhat comparable ideas, they don't work the same and of course, both have no impact at runtime. They're merely for the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Joey's excellent answer, for paths you could use forward slashes:

```
{
  "MyPath": "c:/testmypath"
}
```

This is usually pretty well supported. Or to be super safe, you could just revert them back to regular backslashes:

```
return configuration["MyPath"].Replace("/", @"\");
```

Comment: Good idea. Slashes work for File APIs on Windows without a problem, no need to escape them back. The only place where they are sometimes _not_ supported is in arguments to `cmd` built-ins (as `cmd`'s parser needs to consider options).

Comment: @Joey Which is of course why DOS paths had backslashes for file paths in the first place - IBM DOS used forward slashes for options, and MS DOS had to be compatible with that (they originally used `-` for options, and it was even configurable in early versions).